# Why do I need to do export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>() when using Typescript with React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I've worked a bit with React using JS, but now I'm creating a new project to learn React with Typescript. When I was using JS and needed to use `dispatch`, I just imported useDispatch from react-redux:

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
const AuthAppBar = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const isUserLogged = useSelector(authSelector.isUserLogged);
  const { event } = useGoogleAnalytics();

  const userLogout = () => {
    const userManager = authManager.getUserManager();
    dispatch(authActions.setLoggingOut(true));
    userManager.signoutRedirect({ state: { callbackUrl: routes.home.path } });

    event('Account', 'Logout');
  };

  return <></>;
};
```

But now in this Typescript project the docs says that I need to do like this:

```
// hooks.ts
import { TypedUseSelectorHook, useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import type { RootState, AppDispatch } from './store';

// Use throughout your app instead of plain `useDispatch` and `useSelector`
export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>();


// useGetDeviceById.ts
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useHistory, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useAppDispatch, useAppSelector } from 'src/hooks';

const useGetDeviceById = () => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  // ...
}
```

Why do I need to do it this way?

Comment: Looks like `useAppDispatch` is just a typed version of `useDispatch`.

Comment: To add to what @Bafsky said, you can check that `useAppDispatch()` now has all the types of the reducers in the store when you hover over it in comparison to just using the plain `useDispatch()`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You aren't *required* to do this, but it's a nice convenience factor, and can prevent some errors later.

Normally, you'd have to do this in every component file:

```
// import the RootState type
import { RootState, AppDispatch } from "app/store";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";

function MyComponent() {
  // Specifically mark the `state` arg as being of type RootState
  const todos = useSelector( (state: RootState) => state.todos);

  // Specifically mark `dispatch` as being a type that understands thunks
  const dispatch : AppDispatch = useDispatch();
}
```

Not a huge cost, but it can be annoying to repeat that.  In addition, one of the most common problems we see is people not using the store-specific version of the `Dispatch` type, and having TS tell them they can't dispatch thunks because those aren't plain action objects.

So, for consistency, we recommend that users always create pre-typed versions of the hooks and use them, so they don't accidentally forget to use the right types:

```
import { useAppSelector, useAppDispatch } from "app/hooks";

function MyComponent() {
  // Already knows the state is `RootState`
  const todos = useAppSelector(state => state.todos);

  // Already knows that `dispatch` can accept a thunk
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
}
```

Comment: could someone explain where AppDispatch is coming from?

Comment: It's a type that should be derived from the store: `type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch`: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/typescript-quick-start#define-root-state-and-dispatch-types